# The problem of not recognizing max_length in Django

Tags: django-models, maxlength, makemigrations

```
class ConcerModel(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    singerName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lenght=models.CharField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.singerName


class locationModel (models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Address=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    capacity=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

### The following error is given during the execution of the makemigrations command

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

### ERRORS:

ticketsale.ConcerModel.lenght: (fields.E120) CharFields must define a 'max_length' attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You have a field `lenght` (which is supposed to be `length` I guess) without a `max_length`. Define that and you are good to go.